# SharePoint Online + Power App - how to use make app full-width?

Tags: powerapp, modern-pages

I have Power Apps (Canvas) application (dashboard), and want it to show data in many columns.

I made my app settings 'Landscape' and '16:10 Widescreen', but when I put it to modern Site Page - it takes only part of the page. Is there any way to make it 100%?

[image]

[image]

When we create canvas power apps - it take full screen but placed on SharePoint page they are always smaller..

Comment: I once tried to enlarge and PowerApp screen but came to the conlcusion that it's not possible. It can be done on a normal PowerApp but the SharePoint Forms PowerApps are a slightly different category.

Comment: Thank You much @jimas13! heh :(...